# PHP, link when redirected doesn't work anymore

Tags: php

Currently I'm working with a group on a website where people can plan things and earn badges. For that we made a log in screen. After a user has logged in the user gets redirected to the index.php file. In this file is one link that has to send the user to the index.html file in which people can actualy put tasks or plan things.

The problem is that the link doesn't work. The link only opens when I open it in a new tab but not in the same one. This is the code we used for the login.php file.

```
<?php
require('db.php');
// session_start();
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){

    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

//Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        exit();
        }else{
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
            }
}
```

In the index.php file we used this code:

```
<?php
include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>
<p>This is secure area.</p>
<p><a href="planning/index.html">Ga nu naar de planner</a></p>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's about this row in the index.php file:

```
<p><a href="planning/index.html">Ga nu naar de planner</a></p>
```

When clicked on I get an error loading the page. When opened in a new tab it works fine. Also the CSS doesn't work after logging in. In the URL the login.php is behind the URL. When I remove this (after logging in) the link does work and also the CSS works.

Hopefully you can help us out! Thanks a lot in advance! Hopefully you understand the problem a little :)

EDIT
As asked the file tree: 
https://s27.postimg.org/mswa2dmlf/foto1.jpg
https://s24.postimg.org/ca3lbw3cl/foto2.jpg

First picture is the main map, second picture the planning map!

Comment: Side notes: 1) Please get rid of `stripslashes()` (I hope you haven't enabled Magic Quotes!) 2) Using plain MD5 to hash passwords is not very different from storing then in clear. You can Google hashes for most popular passwords.

Comment: Are you sure the `index.html` file in in the `/planning` directory? Same goes for your CSS files.

Comment: please add your file tree in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `<a href="planning/index.html">` with the full path to the page where you want this to go ... Example ... if your site is www.exemple1.com ...`<a href="http://www.exemple1.com/planning/index.html">`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried it out but is doesn't work out :( Now I have the URL 2 times. It automatically puts the url in front of it. So it's now exemple1.com/www.exemple1.com/planning/index.html

Comment: I bet when you changed you code based on my example you did not add ... "http://" ...  did you ?